# Using OnClick event with PostBackUrl attribute of asp:Button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

I have an `asp:Button` control like this;

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPayCC" CssClass="paymentButton" runat="server" Text="ONAYLA"  
OnClientClick="if(!doPostBack()) return false; frmMaster.target='_blank'" 
PostBackUrl="http://www.google.com" OnClick="btnPayCC_Click" />
```

And `doPostBack` javascript function is;

```
function doPostBack() 
 {
   __doPostBack('<%= btnPayCC.ClientID %>', '');
   return true;
 };
```

When I clicked the button, then it opens new page(google.com) as I wish, 
But do not postback into button control's `OnClick` event.

What is the problem?
How can I solve it?

Comment: You can only PostBack to one place. You're either posting "back" to the google url or you're posting back to your own page. Both can't happen without separate requests.

Comment: Thanks @JoelEtherton, I wonder, is there any alternative solution  to do this job (calling a c# function using doPostBack vs.)?

Comment: I would recommend posting back to your local page, doing whatever verification you need then REposting to google. They are self-contained actions so shouldn't be dependent on each other.

Comment: @MehmetInce you can call your javascript from the code behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I solved it by adding a Response.Redirect("url") at the end of my onClick event for the Button and removing the PostbackUrl attribute from the button so that is uses autopostback to the same url.  IE:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   //do your button click events here
   Response.Redirect("~/url.aspx");
}
```

and

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="Button_Click">
```